# How to remove a help text from the registration form?

Tags: 7, theming, users

I'm writing a custom function to now allow spaces and other special characters for the username on the registration form.

How can I remove the text "Spaces are allowed; punctuation is not allowed except for periods, hyphens, apostrophes, and underscores." on that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  if (!($form_id == 'user_register_form')) {
        return;
  }

  $form['account']['name']['#description'] = 'Username has to be between 5-20 characters long and can only contain letters and numbers.';
}
```